Gradient invariance under orthogonal transformation of coordinates
i was doing exercises of Analisi Matematica 1 Pagani-Salsa, and one of this excercise ask to prove that the gradient of a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is invariant under orthogonal coordinates transformations, that are represented like this: let $y = Mx$ where $M$ is an orthogonal matrix, and the change of coord of the function is $g(y) = f(Mx)$, then the gradient of $g$ should be equal to the gradient of $f$ ($\nabla g (y) = \nabla f (x)$). Now i've tried to derive the partial derivative of $g$ like this, since $f$ is differentiable $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x) = \langle \nabla f(x), v\rangle$$ , where $v$ is any vector, and by chain rule $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(Mx_i) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x) \cdot\frac{\partial Mx_k}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} (x)\cdot\frac{\partial (\sum_{s=1}^{n}M_{ks}x_s)}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} (x)\cdot\ M_{ki} = [M^t\nabla f(x)]_i $$ where $M^t$ is the transpose of $M$. Then $$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_i}(y) = \frac{\partial f (Mx_i)}{\partial Mx_i} = \langle\nabla f(Mx_i), Mx_i\rangle = \langle M^t\nabla f(x_i), Mx_i\rangle $$.
Then i don't know how to going on.

The gradient of a differentiable function $g\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is the unique vector field $\nabla g$ such that
$$
\mathrm d g=\langle \nabla g,\cdot\rangle,
$$
where $\mathrm d g$ is the differential of $g$. Consider $h\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n, \ x\mapsto Mx$. By the chain rule we have
$$
\mathrm d g=\mathrm d(f\circ h)=\mathrm d f\circ \mathrm d h.
$$
At each point $x\in \mathbb R^n$ we have $(\mathrm d h)_x=h$, since $h$ is a linear map. Therefore for each point $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$ we have
$$
(\mathrm d g)_x(v)=((\mathrm d f)_{h(x)}\circ (\mathrm d h)_x)(v)=(\mathrm d f)_{Mx}(Mv)=\langle (\nabla f)_{Mx},Mv\rangle=\langle M^t(\nabla f)_{Mx},v\rangle.
$$
This shows that
$$
(\nabla g)_x=M^t(\nabla f)_{Mx}=M^{-1}(\nabla f)_{Mx},
$$
which in general is not equal to $(\nabla f)_x$. So it's simply not true, that the gradient of $g$ is equal to the gradient of $f$.

Let's consider a concrete example: Let
$$
f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, \ (x,y)\mapsto x^2+2y^2.
$$
Then we have
$$
(\nabla f)_{(x,y)}=\binom{2x}{4y}.
$$
Further let
$$
M:=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
g(x,y):=f(M(x,y)^t)=f(y,x)=y^2+2x^2.
$$
Now note that
$$
(\nabla g)_{(x,y)}=\binom{4x}{2y}\neq (\nabla f)_{(x,y)}.
$$

Probably the exercise meant something different: We have cartesian coordinates $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and use $y=Mx$ to get new coordinates $y=(y^1,\dots,y^n)$ of $\mathbb R^n$. The basis of $\mathbb R^n$ corresponding to the $x$-coordinates is just the canonical basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$; the basis $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ corresponding to the $y$-coordinates is given by
$$
d_i=\sum_{j=1}^n {\partial x^j\over \partial y^i} e_j.
$$
This yields
$$
(\nabla g)_x=M^{-1}(\nabla f)_{Mx}=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n {\partial x^i \over \partial y^k}\partial_{x^k}f(Mx)e_i=\sum_{k=1}^n \partial_{x^k}f(Mx) d_k,
$$
so that the components of $(\nabla g)_x$ w.r.t. the $y$-coordinates coincide with the components of $(\nabla f)_{Mx}$ w.r.t. the $x$-coordinates.
